# How to preserve column names with transpose matrix correlation

Tags: r

I have a simple data frame with normalized gene expression values. The df has genes as row names, samples in each column and expression values as follows:

```
      sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
gene1   1        4       .6     14      20
gene2   5        16      14      1      22
gene3   4        1       99      3      53
gene4   87       2       12      3      19
gene5   33       77      15     14      22
```

I am trying to calculate the correlation between genes in each sample. I have used the code:

```
Mat_1 <- as.matrix(cor(t(df_m)))
```

But the resulting matrix removes my column names and puts the gene names in both rows and columns instead. Is there a way to compute this correlation matrix while preserving the genes and samples names in the rows and columns respectively? Or at least retrieve the sample names for the values so that they can be visualized according to sample?

Comment: It makes sense to compute correlations between rows or between columns, but correlations between a row and a column is not interruptible and would require that the number of genes and samples is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```r
  dat <- data.frame(sample1 = c(1,5,4,87,33), 
           sample2 = c(4,16,1,2,77), 
           sample3 = c(.6,14,99,12,15), 
           sample4 = c(14,1,3,3,14), 
           sample5 = c(20,22,53,19,22))

rownames(dat) <- paste0("gene", 1:5)

cor(t(dat), dat)
#>          sample1     sample2    sample3    sample4    sample5
#> gene1  0.6903946  0.75223370 -0.3819662  0.2896108 -0.4613392
#> gene2 -0.4466371  0.74893869  0.2379466  0.1506124  0.2424242
#> gene3 -0.2759601  0.18105885  0.8857378 -0.0134290  0.8841590
#> gene4 -0.4172298 -0.12982712 -0.3281653  0.7309607 -0.2186932
#> gene5 -0.4621283 -0.03506164 -0.3451630 -0.2862352 -0.3168201

cor(dat$sample1, c(unlist(dat[1,])))
#> [1] 0.6903946
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

But, note that each cell gives you the correlation of the corresponding row and column of the original data.  As displayed above, the upper-left cell is the correlation between the `gene1` row and the `sample1` column in the original data.

Comment: It is not clear what this actually means and it will not work if the number of genes and samples is different.

Comment: @dcarlson you're exactly right, but this is the only possible solution that meets the OP's criteria.  I'm not quite sure what it would mean either and as you rightly point out, it works in this simple example, but is unlikely to work in other real-world contexts.